$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} [(2z+z^2)(\ln(2z+z^2))]$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$
So, I have the following complex function:
$f(z) = 
\begin{cases} 
z^2 + (z-1)(z^2-1) \ln(z^2-1) & \text{if } z \neq 1, -1 \\
1 & \text{if } z = 1 \text{ or } z = -1 
\end{cases}$
I have to prove that $f'(1)=2$
I use the definition of derivative as a limit:
$f'(1)\lim_{w\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(1+w)-f(1)}{w}$ and end up getting $f'(1)=\lim_{w\rightarrow 0} 2+w+(2w+w^2)(\ln(2w+w^2))$.
I'm having trouble with the $\lim_{w\rightarrow 0} (2w+w^2)(\ln(2w+w^2))$ part.
I tried doing $\lim_{w\rightarrow 0} (2w+w^2)(\ln(2w+w^2))=\lim_{w\rightarrow 0} (2w+w^2)(\ln(w)+\ln(2+w))$, but I keep getting that "$\ln(0)$"
Any ideas on how to tackle this?
Thanks in advance

As $w\to0$, $u:=2w+w^2\to0$, so you just need to prove that $\lim_{u\to0} u\log u=0$. But what definition are you taking for the complex logarithm?

$\ln(z^2-1)$ is not defined or not continuous for many values of $z$ other than $\pm1.$

Related.

$ln: \mathbb{C}^{}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $\ln(z)=\ln(|z|)+iArg(z)$
